# highstocks - legend position and refresh legend values on mousemove of multiple charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is the scenario. I've multiple `highstocks` say 10 charts on a single page. Currently I've written 500 lines of code to position the legend, show tooltip and refresh the legend values on mousemove.

No. of legends vary per chart. **On mousemove values of all the legends are updated.** I need to optimize the code I am using `highstocks` v1.2.2. [image: Multiple charts with legends]

Above screenshot shows 2 charts. `Return`, `Basket`, `vs Basket Spread` are legends and it's values are updated on every mousemove.

Please find [this fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/c5wRa/38/). In my case legends are positioned and updated values on mouse move with hundreds of lines of code. **When I move the mouse the legend values of `Return` and `Basket` of first chart and the legend values of `vs Basket Spread` are updated. It's working fine but with lots of `javascript` code. So I need to optimize it less code or with highstocks built-in feature.**

**Update**

User @wergeld has posted [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5wRa/44/). As I've shown in screenshot when cross-hair is being moved over any chart, the legend values of all the charts should be updated.

**Is there anyway to implement the same functionality with less code or is there built-in feature available in `highstocks` ???**

Using [this as a reference](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume).

Comment: So, how are you appending what I assume is the y-value to the legend?

Answer (score 0):

Basic example would be to use the [`events.mouseover`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) methods:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                    var theLegendList = $('#legend');
                    var theSeriesName = this.series.name;
                    var theYValue = this.y;
                    $('li', theLegendList).each(function (l) {
                        if (this.innerText.split(':')[0] == theSeriesName) {
                            this.innerText = theSeriesName + ': ' + theYValue;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming I have modded the `<li>` to be:

```
        $('<li>')
            .css('color', serie.color)
            .text(serie.name + ': NA')
            .click(function () {
            toggleSeries(i);
        })
            .appendTo($legend);
```

You would then need to handle the `mouseout` event but I do not know what you want to do there.
Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/c5wRa/44/).

EDIT:
Here is a [version](http://jsfiddle.net/7g5g0yaj/) using your reference OHLC chart to put the values in a different legend location when any point in the chart is hovered.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        //using the ohlc and volumn data sets created at runtime.
                        var stockVal = ohlc[this.index][4]; // show close value
                        var stockVolume = volume[this.index][1];
                        var theChart = $('#container').highcharts();
                        var theLegendList = $('#legend');
                        $('li', theLegendList).each(function (l) {
                            var legendTitle = theChart.series[l].name;
                            if (l === 0) {
                                this.innerText = legendTitle + ': ' + stockVal;
                            }
                            if (l === 1) {
                                this.innerText = legendTitle + ': ' + stockVolume;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case I need to update legends of all the charts when I move mouse on any chart. So it's like a moving mouse over pane.

Comment: Okay, so extend this code to all those charts. You have an external legend created for each chart. Add the `mouseOver` to each chart so it updates the correct legend. I think what you want is to capture the xAxis index (assuming all charts are using the same category/time for a given index) and then updating each chart's legend text with the value it would have at that xAxis index. Again, doable with this code. You get the index of the point via `this.index`.

Comment: Updated answer using OHLC chart referenced in your edit.